# How to delete only a subset of posted data in firebase

Tags: rest, firebase

Posting data to firebase generate new items similar to the following example:

> log
>   -K4JVL1PZUpMc0r0xYcw
>   -K4jVRhOeL7fH6CoNNI8
>   -K4Jw0Uo0gUcxZ74MWBO

I struggle to find how to e.g. delete entries that is older than x days - preferably with the REST API. Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Where is your code? What does the data look like? If your criteria is "older than x days" then where are you storing the created timestamp that you'll use to query the data? What language are we working in? Have you read the docs on [reading data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html), specifically the section on [queries](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries)? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I post data with Python and the post looks like:
url = ROOTURL+'/sensor/'+dtype+'.json'
post = {
 "v": value,
 "ts": {".sv": "timestamp"}}
datas = json.dumps(post)
requests.put(url, data=datas)

So the timestamps are generated by Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do a range query**.

This technique requires you to have a timestamp property for each record.

Using `orderBy` and `endAt` you can retrieve all of the items before a specified date.

```
curl https://<my-firebase-app>.firebaseio.com/category/.json?orderBy="timestamp"&endAt=1449754918067
```

Then with the result, you can delete each individual item.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
That is kind of brute force solution - and requires many many individual ReST calls. 
I had hoped that the delete ReST call had some conditionals so it was possible to e.g. delete posts older than 3 days

Comment: This all depends on your data structure. If you optimize your structure for these kind of calls, then it becomes less brute force. But you can easily create a script to do this operation.

Comment: Currently this is the only solution. Let me know if you need any other clarification. If this works please mark it as accepted, it's good to keep the unanswered queue clean.